# Have `std::ostreambuf_iterator` write to a string instead of `std::cout` in this example

Tags: c++11

I am going through an example of `std::regex_replace`. The example uses this

```
std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),source.begin(), source.end(), search, "");
```

`std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout)` writes to `std::cout` how do I make it write to a string instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stringstream:

```
std::stringstream str;
std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(str),source.begin(), source.end(), search, "");
// str.str() is a string with the result
```